# How to pass object instead of string in Nativescript-vue with typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

## I want to implement PromptDialog as in [{N} Playground Code](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=NxjdeL)

```
import dialogs from "tns-core-modules/ui/dialogs";
 
  export default {
    methods: {
            onButtonTap() {
                console.log("Button was pressed");
                prompt({
                    title: "Email Prompt",
                    message: "Provide your email address:",
                    okButtonText: "OK",
                    cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
                    defaultText: "name@domain.com",
                    inputType: dialogs.inputType.email
                }).then(result => {
                    console.log(`Dialog result: ${result.result},
                text: ${result.text}`);
                });
            }
        },
  }
```

But Vetur is giving following Typescript error.

```
Argument of type '{ title: string; message: string; okButtonText: string; cancelButtonText: string; defaultText: string; inputType: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

This is just example code in [nativescript-vue prompt documentation](https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/elements/dialogs/prompt/#app) but typescript adaption.

### Basic use

```
    forgotPassword() {
      prompt('Your message to the user', 'Suggested user input').then(result => {
        console.log(`Dialog result: ${result.result}, text: ${result.text}`);
      });
    }
```

Vetur Error:

```
Property 'then' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

Comment: `prompt` accepts a `string` as parameter, if we are talking about this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt

Comment: PromptDialog as in [{NativeScript} Playground Code](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=NxjdeL)

Comment: The implication is that the API has incorrect type declarations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a miss leading of documentation. There is no API called **prompt**. It should be **dialogs.prompt**.
Correct example

```
<script lang="ts">
    import * as dialogs from "tns-core-modules/ui/dialogs";
     export default {
        methods: {
            onButtonTap() {
                console.log("Button was pressed");
                dialogs.prompt({
                    title: "Email Prompt",
                    message: "Provide your email address:",
                    okButtonText: "OK",
                    cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
                    defaultText: "name@domain.com",
                    inputType: dialogs.inputType.email
                }).then(result => {
                    console.log(`Dialog result: ${result.result},
                text: ${result.text}`);
                });
            }
        },

        data() {
            return {};
        }
    };
</script>
```